# Variable within an share button, ionic 3

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to put a variable like `{{data.title}}`, inside the button

```
<button onclick = "window.plugins.socialsharing.share (data.title)"> message only </ button>
```

but I do not know how to do it.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: can you elaborate what are you trying to achieve? pass data.title to a method? can you share full code of your template including ngFor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<button (click)="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(data.title)"> message only </button>
```

Also it would be a better practice to write a method inside your ts file that already calls the plugin:

```
<button (click)="shareClicked(data.title)"> message only </button>
```

In your TS:

```
shareClicked(title) {
    window.plugins.socialsharing.share(title)
}
```